# Span at the bottom of Parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a flex container in which I have two boxes which are side by side (and collapse in one column when the screen is too small).

Now, when boxes are side by side, I've set that they have the same height, like in the following image.
[image]

Now, what I want to achieve is to put the EDIT button of both boxes at the bottom (this means that only the EDIT button of the box with less content will need to move).

I've searched, but the solution are to use position absolute, because one of the two boxes won't need it, and if I put position absolute on both EDIT button, the box on the right will have less height because it won't count the EDIT button anymore.

I tried to play with flex, but I rather not set the boxes as display flex.

There may be some solution with Jquery, I've read something about it, but it was just something like "You could achieve that with Jquery!" but.. I honestly don't know how.

```css
#parent {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 50px);
  
}

.box:last-of-type {
  background-color: green;
}
  
  
.box:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}

.cool-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button-container {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="box">
    <form class="cool-form">
      <h1>Box on left</h1>
      <p>This is a shorter box</p>

      <span class="button-container">
        <span class="button">EDIT</span>      
      </span>
    </form>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    <form class="cool-form">
      <h1>Box on right</h1>
      <p>This is</p>
      <p>a</p>
      <p>bigger</p>
      <p>waaay bigger</p>
      <p>Box</p>

      <span class="button-container">
        <span class="button">EDIT</span>
      </span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I rather not set the boxes as display flex!* - This is actualy simple...if you do.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I added a Code Snippet with the same problem.
@Paulie_D The fact is that, by now, i've already filled some boxes and using display: flex would require me to repair a lot of them. I know it would be easy, but I'm leaving that as last choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `flexbox` to these divs (using `flex-direction:column`) seems minimally invasive (which was, perhaps a concern).

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Then you can give the button container `margin-top:auto` and it's auomatically pushed to the bottom.

Then it's just a matter of aligning it horizontally/centrally

```
.button-container {
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```css
#parent {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 50px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box:last-of-type {
  background-color: green;
}

.box:first-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}

.button-container {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box on left</h1>
    <p>This is a shorter box</p>

    <span class="button-container">
      <span class="button">EDIT</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <h1>Box on right</h1>
    <p>This is</p>
    <p>a</p>
    <p>bigger</p>
    <p>waaay bigger</p>
    <p>Box</p>

    <span class="button-container">
      <span class="button">EDIT</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about that, but the problem is that could happen that the two boxes only contains a form, in which I have the .button-container. I have edited the snippet: as you can see, now I can't use the display on the box because the .button-container is a children of the form, and if I use the display flex on the form, the problem is that form does not take up all the height of the parent.

Comment: Sure but you just have to make form 100% height, with `flex:1` then start again making the form a flexbox just like the parent(s).

Comment: Yeah, I think it's  the only solution that doesn't exploit `position: absolute`.. Thank you